# Mongodb aggregate $add value by _id

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I'm trying to create an aggregate of the most viewed element (authors).

Here is my collection of users:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6cc5058b456b"),
  "history" : {
    "authors" : [
      {
        "name" : "michou",
        "count" : {
          "all" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014" : NumberLong(1),
          "201408" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014w35" : NumberLong(1)
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccb058b4570"),
  "history" : {
    "authors" : [
      {
        "name" : "petitBonhommeEnMousse",
        "count" : {
          "all" : NumberLong(2),
          "2014" : NumberLong(2),
          "201408" : NumberLong(2),
          "2014w35" : NumberLong(2)
        }
      },
      {
        "name" : "lordVador",
        "count" : {
          "all" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014" : NumberLong(1),
          "201408" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014w35" : NumberLong(1)
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccf058b456c"),
  "history" : {
    "authors" : [
      {
        "name" : "lordVador",
        "count" : {
          "all" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014" : NumberLong(1),
          "201408" : NumberLong(1),
          "2014w35" : NumberLong(1)
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I'd like to get is the list of the number of time a user saw an author during the last three weeks.

For that, when a user sees a page, I increase the value of the key "2014w35", "2014w36"... (the number of the week of the year).

Here is a first attempt:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { history_updated: "20140829" } },
    { $unwind: "$history.authors" },
    { $group :
      {
        "_id" : "$history.authors.name",
        "total2014w35" : {"$sum"  : "$history.authors.count.2014w35"},
        "total2014w34" : {"$sum"  : "$history.authors.count.2014w34"},
        "total2014w33" : {"$sum"  : "$history.authors.count.2014w33"}
      }
    },
    { $project: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "total" : {
          $add : [
            "$total2014w35",
            "$total2014w34",
            "$total2014w33"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Which returns a list of the authors seen and how many times, but not separated by user. it's the total:

```
{ "_id" : "lordVador", "total" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : "petitBonhommeEnMousse", "total" : NumberLong(2) }
{ "_id" : "michou", "total" : NumberLong(1) }
```

My second attemps was to group by _id:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [
    { $match: { history_updated: "20140829" } },
    { $unwind: "$history.authors" },
    {
      $group :
      {
        "_id" : "$_id",
        ....
```

Which, of course, returns the total of authors view by user. But without author detail.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccb058b4570"), "total" : NumberLong(3) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccf058b456c"), "total" : NumberLong(1) }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6cc5058b456b"), "total" : NumberLong(1) }
```

**What I'd like to have** is a mix of both. I'd like to have, for each user (document in the collection) the list of authors, with for each, how many times the user saw him/her, during the last 3 weeks.

Something like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccb058b4570"), [{ "lordVador" : NumberLong(3) },{ "michou" : NumberLong(1) } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6ccf058b456c"), [{ "petitBonhommeEnMousse" : NumberLong(1) } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6cc5058b456b"), [{ "lordVador" : NumberLong(1) } ] }
```

Do any of you have any idea how to mix them?

Comment: I don't understand what you're after. Please explain more clearly. What is a user? Each of the documents you give as examples represent a user? In that case, it seems like the info you want is pretty much just in the original doc. What are the weird keys like "2014w35"? Why are you (apparently) using values as keys? Why aren't you using dates?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it's not clear. I updated my question. Yes, each document in the collection is one user. I'd like to have, for each user (document in the collection) the list of authors, with for each, how many times the user saw him/her, during the last 3 weeks. 2014w35 represent the 35th week of 2014. I did not use dates because I store it by weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Aggregation framework, you cannot obtain a map between the authors names and their counts. At most you can obtain, are two different arrays considered to be associative:

```
db.user.aggregate([
{$match: {"history_updated": "20140829" } },
{$unwind:"$history.authors"},
{$group:{"_id":"$_id","authors":{$push:"$history.authors.name"},
         "visits_last_three_mnths":{$push:{$add:["$history.authors.count.201408","$history.authors.count.2014w35"]}}}
}
])
```

Sample o/p:(Have changed the ids, numbers, removed an user from your example)

```
{ "_id" : 2, "authors" : [ "petitBonhommeEnMousse", "lordVador" ], "visits_last_three_mnths" : [75,150 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "authors" : [ "michou" ], "visits_last_three_mnths" : [ 300 ] }
```

**Note:** The associativity is preserved bewteen the "authors" and the "visits_last_three_mnths" arrays, by their indices. However, the way you want your result can be achieved via Map-Reduce.

The modified Dataset i used,

```
db.user.insert({
  "_id" : 1,
  "history" : {
    "authors" : [
      {
        "name" : "michou",
        "count" : {
          "all" : 400,
          "2014" : 300,
          "201408" : 200,
          "2014w35" : 100
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
db.user.insert({
  "_id" : 2,
  "history" : {
    "authors" : [
      {
        "name" : "petitBonhommeEnMousse",
        "count" : {
          "all" : 200,
          "2014" : 100,
          "201408" : 50,
          "2014w35" : 25
        }
      },
      {
        "name" : "lordVador",
        "count" : {
          "all" : 300,
          "2014" : 200,
          "201408" : 100,
          "2014w35" : 50
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Here is my shot on this using Map reduce(with the same dataset as above), hope this helps:

```
var map = function(){emit(this._id,{"author":this.history.authors});}
var reduce = function(userid,authors_arr){
var reduced = {"user_views":[]};
for(var i in authors_arr)
{
    var author_array = authors_arr[i];
    var authors = author_array.author;
    for(var j in authors)
    {
        var author = authors[j];
        reduced.user_views.push({"author_name":author.name,"views":author.count.all});
    }
}
return reduced;
}

db.user.mapReduce(map,reduce,{ out: "output" }) 

[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "value": {
      "user_views": [
        {
          "author_name": "michou",
          "views": 400
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "value": {
      "user_views": [
        {
          "author_name": "petitBonhommeEnMousse",
          "views": 200
        },
        {
          "author_name": "lordVador",
          "views": 300
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

**Note:** You need to change your key naming conventions, eg.'201408' is not a valid java script attribute.
Once you have changed them, you can modify the "reduce" function to obtain the sum of weekly views.

Comment: Hi, You example does not work, it returns nothing. But I think you're right, I'll use a map-reduce. Aggregation framwork is faster to run, but it seems impossible to acheive what I want.

Comment: Yes, it would not, if you copied and pasted away directly.It contained indicators (",..") for indicating multiple week count addition. Have removed it now. Also, i had to make some changes locally to your code such as chaging the ids, removing some records. Have included the dataset i used. And yes Map-reduce is the solution.

Comment: Ah, no it wasn't that, of course I change the ... it just I missspelling the collection's name... Yes it's works. But I can't order them by the most used or limit to the three most used. I'll use map-reduce than. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I have added an implementation using Map reduce, hope you can use that as a starting point to frame your solution.

Comment: Hmm.. This is embarassing.. If I do exactly your map-reduce, output returns: { "_id" : ObjectId("54008ac8145a6cc5058b456b"), "value" : { "author" : [ { "name" : "michou", "count" : { "all" : NumberLong(1), "2014" : NumberLong(1), "201408" : NumberLong(1), "2014w35" : NumberLong(1) } } ] } } I search but didn't find how the hell this data came into outpout! No trace of user_views or anything. And btw, I can't figure why do you embed this.history.authors into an object in the emit()?

Comment: @ConstantinGuay you can try debugging the code by pasting your dataset, and map reduce functions in http://targetprocess.github.io/mongo-mapreduce-debug-online/  . make sure to check what input is being passed onto the reduce function.

Comment: Ah good tool, thanks. I was able to make it work by adding the loop to read each autor in the map function. Thanks again for your help, now I have to improve the thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try "$addToSet" for your second attemp. Add authors and read numbers to the set. If the author is unique for each user, "$push" is ok.
**http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/**